# Implementing similar functions in a function with (Input) Parameters?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following function to launch Skype from my Ionic app:

```
myApp.controller("launchSkypeCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {  
        $scope.launchSkype = function launchSkype() {
            var scheme;             
            if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
                scheme = 'skype://';
                } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
                scheme = 'com.skype.raider';
                } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
                scheme = 'skype:';
                } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
                scheme = 'skype:';
            }

            navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
                navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
                    }, function(error) { /* error */
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "Skype not startet!",
                        content: "Skype not startet!"
                    })
                });
                }, function(error) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Skype not installed",
                    content: "Skype not installed on this device. Please install it!"
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I also have the similar function, which starts Google Hangouts:

```
myApp.controller("launchHangoutsCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {  
        $scope.launchHangouts = function launchSkype() {
            var scheme;

            if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
                scheme = 'gtalk://';
                } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
                scheme = 'com.google.android.talk';
                } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
                scheme = 'gtalk:';
                } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
                scheme = 'gtalk:';
            }

            navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
                navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
                    }, function(error) { /* error */
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "Google Hangouts not started!",
                        content: "Google Hangouts not started!"
                    })
                });
                }, function(error) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Google Hangouts not installed!",
                    content: "Google Hangouts not installed! Please install it!"
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As can be seen, only the links of Apps are different. Otherwise everything is the same. Errors are of course linked with the app name. My question is **how can I put these two same functions with different app links in a function?** I have more then two functions. I will thus avoid the repetition of the same functions.  **How can I output the error messages of the respective apps in a single function?** **How would the function which includes the above features look like?** **How would the call of the start of the respective app look like?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the corresponding strings as a parameter. In this case an object:

```
function launchApp($ionicPopup, appConfig) {
    var scheme;

    if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
        scheme = appConfig.iosScheme;
    } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
        scheme = appConfig.androidScheme;
    } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
        scheme = appConfig.wpScheme;
    } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
        scheme = appConfig.windows8Scheme;
    }

    navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
        navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
            }, function(error) { /* error */
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: appConfig.appName + " not started!",
                content: appConfig.appName + " not started!"
            })
        });
        }, function(error) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: appConfig.appName + " not installed!",
            content: appConfig.appName + " not installed! Please install it!"
        })
    });    
}

myApp.controller("launchSkypeCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var skypeConfig = {
            "appName": "Skype",
            "iosScheme": "skype://",
            "androidScheme": "com.skype.raider",
            "wpScheme": "skype:",
            "windows8Scheme": "skype:"
        }
        $scope.launchSkype = launchApp($ionicPopup, skypeConfig);
    }
});

myApp.controller("launchHangoutsCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {  
        var hangoutConfig = {
            "appName": "Google Hangouts",
            "iosScheme": "gtalk://",
            "androidScheme": "com.google.android.talk:",
            "wpScheme": "gtalk:",
            "windows8Scheme": "gtalk:"
        }
        $scope.launchHangouts = launchApp($ionicPopup, hangoutConfig);
    }
});
```

Where you define the objects is up to you.

**Edit:**
To get `$scope.launchSykpe` and `$scope.launchHangouts` to be functions instead of calls, use the below launchApp function:

```
function launchApp($ionicPopup, appConfig) {
    return function() {
        var scheme;

        if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
            scheme = appConfig.iosScheme;
        } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
            scheme = appConfig.androidScheme;
        } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
            scheme = appConfig.wpScheme;
        } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
            scheme = appConfig.windows8Scheme;
        }

        navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
            navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
                }, function(error) { /* error */
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: appConfig.appName + " not started!",
                    content: appConfig.appName + " not started!"
                })
            });
            }, function(error) {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: appConfig.appName + " not installed!",
                content: appConfig.appName + " not installed! Please install it!"
            })
        });
    };    
}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work now as inteded.

Comment: Your example works but after I implemented your proposal both apps, so Skype and Hangouts are started when I start the main application. Without that I have executed them. In my examples they don't start at startup. Only when I click on the "Launch Skype" button or "launch Hangouts" button they are started. How can I prevent that they don't start right at the start?

Comment: My call of the functions: for Skype `ng-controller="launchSkypeCtrl"` `ng-click="launchSkype()"` and for Hangouts `ng-controller="launchHangoutsCtrl"` `ng-click="launchHangouts()"`

Comment: I thought it might be `onDeviceReady()` or `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` the reason. But when I remove both of them from the method the function doesn't longer work. I would look forward to a proposal very much. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is in defining `$scope.launchSyke = launchApp(...)`. I didn't think of that at first. It directly calls the function instead of defining it as such. For it to work like you want it to, the launchApp function has to return a function. See my edit.

Comment: I have a similar question [hier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081094/avoiding-the-repetition-of-angularjs-function) as above. Maybe you can help me? thanks.